# Getting error when I deploy WAR by IntelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I try to deploy my web application on Tomcat by IntelliJ. This application is in WAR. I run server and start deploy, but I get the following error:

```
cze 21, 2017 2:18:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean invoke
SEVERE: Exception invoking method createStandardContext
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have Tomcat v. 7.0.62 bundle with Liferay Portal 6.2 CE GA6 and IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2017.1.
What can I do with this problem?

**EDIT:**
My run configuration in IntelliJ:
[image: run configuration]

Comment: in your server configuration there is a tab where you define the context of your application, probably it's blank there

Comment: @RamonMarques No, I have `/` context here :(

Comment: `SEVERE: Exception invoking method createStandardContext
java.lang.NullPointerException` fix that NPE and it will work.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson But how to fix it it configuration problem? I didn't change anything in my code

Answer (score 0):

Change run configuration to war:exploded and try again. If isn't share your intellij run configuration. It seems its a problem with your code.

Comment: I have `war:exploded` artifacts set but it not help. And code is good because I can run app outside of IntelliJ without any problem.

Comment: what do you want to know about run configuration?

Comment: Are you able to run tomcat without war using Intellij ? If you are using some specific configuration related for tomcat then check instance option in configuration.

Comment: yes, without this WAR I can run Tomcat without error. I think my configuration is not specific. I edit my question to show it. Do you need any other information about run configuration?

Comment: In your intellij server configuration tab you have something run instance like checkbox check that and give a hit. It should work.

Comment: sorry I don't understand. About which tab and which checkbox do you mean?

Comment: See you screen shot and you have one tab call "server" . In right bottom corner you have two check box check there.